# How to load data into spark dataframe from text file without knowing the schema of the data?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a text file in hadoop, I need to sort it using its second column using spark java api. I am using data frame but I am not sure about its columns.
It may have dynamic columns,means I don't know about the exact number of columns.

How can I proceed? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: i tried by splitting it and then tried to sort using swap technique but was not helpful.

Comment: can you share some rows of the text file ?

Comment: how are you splitting? i mean what is separator char....is  it comma separated ? if it is comma separated then you could use spark csv to create dataframe and `df.sort` on the second column. no need to worry about schema. after converting dataframe, df schema is your data schema

Comment: Sequence  timestamp  value  tag .This is sample row and i want to sort it using 2nd column which is time stamp. I am able to sort using 2nd column by mentioning schema manually. But the thing is that the data may contains more or less number of columns but 2nd column will always same.Input data is tab separated file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is I'm trying to give an csv example in scala (not java)

You can use Spark csv api to create dataframes and sort based on any column you want. 
If you have any limitations please see below way.

#### Fixed number of Columns :

Starting with  below example of fixed number of Columns..
 You can follow this example.

where data looks like for ebay.csv :

> “8213034705,95,2.927373,jake7870,0,95,117.5,xbox,3”

```
//  SQLContext entry point for working with structured data
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
// this is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a DataFrame.
import sqlContext.implicits._
// Import Spark SQL data types and Row.
import org.apache.spark.sql._

//define the schema using a case class
case class Auction(auctionid: String, bid: Float, bidtime: Float, bidder: String, bidderrate: Integer, openbid: Float, price: Float, item: String, daystolive: Integer)


 val auction = sc.textFile("ebay.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(p => 
Auction(p(0),p(1).toFloat,p(2).toFloat,p(3),p(4).toInt,p(5).toFloat,p(6).toFloat,p(7),p(8).toInt )).toDF()

// Display the top 20 rows of DataFrame 
auction.show()
// auctionid  bid   bidtime  bidder         bidderrate openbid price item daystolive
// 8213034705 95.0  2.927373 jake7870       0          95.0    117.5 xbox 3
// 8213034705 115.0 2.943484 davidbresler2  1          95.0    117.5 xbox 3 …


// Return the schema of this DataFrame
auction.printSchema()
root
 |-- auctionid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bid: float (nullable = false)
 |-- bidtime: float (nullable = false)
 |-- bidder: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bidderrate: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- openbid: float (nullable = false)
 |-- price: float (nullable = false)
 |-- item: string (nullable = true)
 |-- daystolive: integer (nullable = true)

auction.sort("auctionid") // this will sort first column i.e auctionid
```

### Variable number of Columns ([since `Case` class with Array parameter is possible](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/SCALA/Case+class+with+array+parameters)):

you can use like below pseudocode,  where first 4 elements are fixed and remaining all are variable array...

Since you are only inserted to sort on second column so this will work out and all other data will be there in array for that particular row, for later use.

```
case class Auction(auctionid: String, bid: Float, bidtime: Float, bidder: String, variablenumberofColumnsArray:String*)

 val auction = sc.textFile("ebay.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(p => 
Auction(p(0),p(1).toFloat,p(2).toFloat,p(3),p(4).toInt, VariableNumberOfColumnsArray or any complex type like Map ).toDF()

    auction.sort("auctionid") // this will sort first column i.e auctionid
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I will try this with Java.

Comment: I am able do it for known column no.s but facing difficulties for unknown no. of columns.

Comment: Okay, Have you added to Array<String> or List<String> ? First 4 or 5 cols you can take with fixed datatype remaining all i.e 5... n will go in to an array. thats all

Comment: yaa, I am trying with that.